# Adding int[] matrix into ArrayList in Java, but got an error

Tags: java, arraylist

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> al= new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    int[][] mat= new int[row][col];
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            mat[i][j]=s.nextInt();
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        al.add(mat[i]);
    }
```

**int[] cannot be converted to ArrayList
al.add(mat[i]);**

Comment: Well, an `int[][]` is an array of arrays. So, `mat[i]` is returning an `int[]`. But an `int[]` is not an `ArrayList<Integer>`, so the call to `al.add` obviously fails. What do you _want_ to happen instead?

Comment: also valid: `al.add(List.of((mat[i]));` using List.of to wrap the int[], but to ensure mutability, it would be better to use `al.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of((mat[i]))));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### An `ArrayList` is not an array

You define an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) that contains `ArrayList` objects. But you are attempting to put an array of `int` primitive values. An array is *not* an `ArrayList`. So you received an error explaining that you are violating the type system. You cannot put bananas in a collection that holds cats.

#### Define a list of arrays: `List < int[] >`

Instead, define your `ArrayList` as containing an array:

```
ArrayList < int[] > list = new ArrayList < int[] > ( );
```

Notice that you need not repeat the parameterized type on the right side of the EQUALS sign. In modern Java, the compiler can infer the type by looking at the left side of EQUALS.

```
ArrayList < int[] > list = new ArrayList <> ( );
```

Also, it is generally best to use the highest superclass or superinterface that provides your needed functionality. So you can refer to your `ArrayList` as a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html). In Java 21+, you could use [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html) ([JEP 431](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431)).

```
List < int[] > list = new ArrayList < int[] > ( );
```

Full example code:

```java
// Prepare.
List < int[] > list = new ArrayList <> ( );
int rows = 3, cols = 3, counter = 1;
int[][] mat = new int[ rows ][ cols ];

// Populate array.
for ( int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i ++ )
{
    for ( int j = 0 ; j < cols ; j ++ )
    {
        mat[ i ][ j ] = counter ++ ;
    }
}

// Populate ArrayList.
for ( int index = 0 ; index < rows ; index ++ )
{
    list.add ( mat[ index ] );
}

// Report.
list.forEach ( ints -> System.out.println ( Arrays.toString ( ints ) ) );
```

When run:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```